# Unaswered questions list shows some questions with answers to them

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions

Is this something that's a site-wide problem or just something to do with my user settings? If I go to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/unanswered I get a couple questions scattered on the list with a few answers already.

Is the Unanswered list supposed to show all questions with no *accepted* answers or is it like SO where all listed questions should have no answers of any kind?

Strangely enough, this Meta site only shows questions with *no* answers at all, like I would expect in the main GameDev site.

Answer (score 3):

We define unanswered, as specified on the upper right of that page:

> ## 175
>
> questions with **no upvoted answers**

Comment: That clears it up. It was confusing, having seen the questions picked differently than on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To the left of the 'Unanswered Questions' header, there is a navigation element that lets you select which types of unanswered questions you would like to see.

I'm guessing you have it set to 'votes', or probably newest. If you want to see questions with no answers at all, just select that option.